# Is there any possible way to give a <p> or a <h1> Tag. Something like a "src"?

Tags: html

I want to create Websites for small companies like restaurants. But i can imagine that i will often get called when they need help "Changing the text". Because they simply doesnt know better. Then i often  will have do it for them. But there might be another way?

Image changing is simple. Just rename any Picture you want. 
Like: 
indexPicture.jpg

Everyone easily can replace those jpg. They simply rename any picture to indexPicture.jpg (preferable same size).

But when it comes changing to text. I can imagine a customer, that destroys html code. and removed some tags like (30 min work). Because he doesn't know better.

Can't I bind some text file to a `<p>` tag? So they simply have to open it and write something new.

Are there any better method?

Like a free App, they can open every website and simply drag and drop changes or select a `<p>` tag and simply rename it?

Comment: Why not simply use one of the web site building tools that allows page editing?  Some users will be able to do this themselves and some will need your help but at least it will be easier than building those functions yourself.  many hosting providers will also give you a percentage of the hosting so over time this builds an income for you

Comment: The answer is simple, use a CMS when you set up sites for small businesses, for instance Wordpress, which I generally hate, but is great for people who have no idea what they are doing, and the customer can easily add content etc. themselves. With Visual Composer there's even drag&drop available.

Comment: Hiya! You can probably do something with iframes or something similar, but that would be a crappy solution, so why not look at server-side languages such as php, which were made with such things in mind. You can also make themes for other cms which are made in such languages, and that way you won't have to learn a new language. If you want to go the cms route try WordPress or Drupal. Good luck!

Comment: So far thanks for your answers. But i dont like Wordpress. And i won't start with other site building tools. I want to improve my coding skills.

So is there no other way? I cant imagine...

Comment: @ThoLi: No, you need a serverside (or even build-level) solution. HTML won't do this for you (nor is doing this clientside a good idea at all). Your problem is exactly what CMS were made for, so you should choose one.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that's really supported in basic HTML5, so the simple answer to a simple question is: no.

But life is never that simple in the modern web. If you're using a client-side templating framework like [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) or [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) (both are JavaScript frameworks which are freely available) you can code the pages to load fragments of text from disparate files which your client may have an easier time editing. I don't believe posting example code here is valuable to the question since that's basically a tutorial on how [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) work. There are great tutorials and examples on their sites.

Comment: People who can't be trusted with HTML markup surely won't bother with React or Angular.

Comment: I'm not sure how HTML markup trust comes into play here - React/Angular is what the web developer is using to build the page, the customer would only be editing plaintext files which get loaded and presented by the React/Angular layer on the client-side. There is separation of concern inherent in that scenario.

Comment: Thank you this seems to help on first view.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments the most accurate thing I can think of is to use a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). These are very helpful when changing the content of your site. Some examples are Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla. You can have a look here: https://www.ucl.ac.uk/building-great-websites/managing-your-website/using-a-cms

I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try a shtml file instead? No CMS needed. I recently found out about this when creating my own HTML5 site as I wanted an easy way to edit a common footer rather than going through all the pages.

Just create a folder with the necessary files (Every paragraph maybe) and include it in the main file using a code like this:

```
<!--#include virtual="../filename.shtml" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you didn't want to use a CMS such as WordPress, which as the comments suggest would be a really effective solution.

I once had an issue where I couldn't use a CMS cause I didn't have Cpanel access and what we essentially did was the follow.

1. Define a XML file, with clearly defined tags for each section of the
   website that the client may want to change periodically.
2. Access the XML file through PHP(something like SimpleXML), and
   display the tags/relevant content in the page.
3. Create a backend that allows the client to view/update content
   through forms.

Alternatively, you may use a similar solution with databases and give forms for editing.